# Regex for matching certain url

Tags: javascript, regex

It's should match those urls

```
https://example.com/id/username/
http://example.com/id/username/
https://www.example.com/id/username
http://example.com/id/username/
```

basically it's should start with `http` or `https` when maybe `www` when `example.com` and `/id` and last is username which could be anything, and `/` is not always in end

username could be anything

I got this so far:

```
  if (input.match(/http\:\/\/example\.com/i)) {
    console.log('-');
  }
```

also how to check with regex if urls ends with 7 number like `1234567/` or `3523173`. `/` not always in end

Comment: Please give the urls where it will **not match**

Comment: anything else shouldn't much

Comment: Please be more precise: are the ids only numerical or alphanumerical (including letters, that is). What about the usernames? Can they contain numbers, `-`, `.` or any other chars?

Comment: Can you add some valid/invalid samples?

Comment: ids is letters only in this case, they cant contain `-` or `.` only letter, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regular expression

```
http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)example.com\/id\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

You can change [a-zA-Z0-9] as per your username format if you required. See following example:

- [a-zA-Z0-9]+  ==> Username contain Uppercase, Lowercase, Number. (john008)
- [a-zA-Z]+  ===> Username contain Uppercase, Lowercase. (john)
- [0-9]+ ===> Username contain only Number. (123456)

Comment: how about urls without `www.` it seems not to much those

Comment: You can use this with www. or without www.
All URLs with or without will are matched.

Comment: idk maybe im doing something wrong but `https://example.org/id/username` doesnt mactch

Comment: Are you want to use in javascript?

Comment: var regex = /http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)example.com\/id\/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/ig;
if ( regex .test(input) ) {
        console.log('-');
}

Answer (score 0):

`https?\:\/\/(www\.)?example\.com\/id\/([a-zA-Z]+)\/?`

Comment: https?:\/\/(www\.)?example\.com\/id\/\w+\/? seems better to me as a username can, in most cases, also contain numbers.

Comment: at the time of answering the username was limited to letters only

Answer (score 0):

Without further specification you could use

```
\bhttps?:.+?example\.com\/[a-zA-Z]+\/\w+\/?(?=\s|\Z)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/kZyrcb/2/).

---

This is

```
\b                   # a word boundary
https?:              # http/https:
.+?                  # anything else afterwards, lazily
example\.com         # what it says
\/[a-zA-Z]+\/\w+\/?  # /id/username with / optional
(?=\s|\Z)            # followed by a whitespace or the end of the string
```